# Where I handle API calls in react-native and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm building an Android app using `react-native` + `redux` + `immutable`

I structured my app like this

```
/src
 -/components
 -/actions (where I have action types and actions)
 -/reducers
 -/api (I'm not sure if I'm doing this right)
```

Ok, so I have a action where I need to make an API call with fetch like this:

```
import * as types from './casesTypes'

export function getCases() {
    return {
      type: types.GET_CASES
    }
}
```

This is the cases reducer:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  isLoading: false,
  cases: null
})
export default function cases(state = initialState, action = {}) {

    switch(action.type) {

        case types.REQUEST_CASES:
          return state.set('isLoading', true)

        case types.RECIVE
          return state.set('cases', //set here the array that I recive from api call)

        default:
          return state
    }
}
```

So, the thing is that I dont really understand, where should I make the API call so that in the reducer I can merge my initial state with what I recive from the API call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your app structure is sound.

I also recommand the usage of redux-thunk to handle the dispatch. Here is how it would work in your case:

Let's say you have 'cases' as part of your state tree.
I would put the API call in your action as you suggested to fetch new cases:

```
import * as types from './casesTypes'

export function getCases() {
    return fetch(...)
             ...
             .then((json) => {
               dispatch({         
                 type: types.RECEIVED_CASES,
                 isLoading: false,
                 cases: json,
               }
}
```

And now in your reducer just get the newly dispatched action to merge the new cases with the state tree:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  isLoading: false,
  cases: null
})

export default function cases(state = initialState, action = {}) {

    switch(action.type) {

        case types.REQUEST_CASES:
          return state.set('isLoading', true)

        case types.RECEIVED_CASES:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            cases: state.cases.merge(action.cases),
          });

        default:
          return state
    }
}
```

I am currently working with this structure and it works pretty well. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You should try out [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga), They are redux middlewares created to handle asynchronous actions like making an API call.

check out this project that used redux-thunk: [sound-redux-native](https://github.com/fraserxu/soundredux-native)